# Why memoization can speed up factorial in Python even if there is no repeated computing?

Tags: python, algorithm, memoization

Here's my code.

```
import timeit

fac_mem = {}

def fac(k):
  if k < 2: return 1
  if k not in fac_mem:
    fac_mem[k] = k*fac(k-1)
return fac_mem[k]

def fact(k):
  if k < 2: return 1
  return k*fact(k-1)

if __name__ == "__main__": 
  print timeit.timeit("fac(7)","from __main__ import fac")
  print timeit.timeit("fact(7)","from __main__ import fact")
  print timeit.timeit("fac(70)","from __main__ import fac")
  print timeit.timeit("fact(70)","from __main__ import fact")
```

Here's output

```
0.236774399224
0.897065011572
0.217623144304
14.1952226578
```

Well, before the program run, the dict is empty, why memoization still sped up factorial? I mean, the number of invocation is the same for these 2 version.
Then I changed the code a bit, moved the dict into the function.

```
def fac(k):
  fac_mem = {}
  if k < 2: return 1
  if k not in fac_mem:
    fac_mem[k] = k*fac(k-1)
  return fac_mem[k]
```

The output changed

```
1.92900857225
0.910026658388
25.5475004875
14.2164999769
```

Why slower? Is that because the value generated inside the function is stored in stack temporarily? Variable outside is global, but what makes it so faster?
Would somebody please be kind enough to clear it up for me? I'd be grateful.

Comment: Better question: why did CS adopt the ridiculous term _memoization_?

Comment: @JeremyWest http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization#Etymology

Comment: @ChristopheBiocca Yeah, I understand the etymology. Just because there's a reason doesn't mean it is a good one :). Every time I see that word I cringe. It just _looks_ like a typo!

Comment: @JeremyWest I thought it was a typo at first too when I learned about it a few weeks ago! But then I eventually got used to it and now I quite like the word. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run `timeit.timeit` without specifying an argument to the keyword `number`, it executes the code that you pass it 1000000 times. If you keep a global dictionary called `fac_mem` in the global scope for Python, it will save the results of the first execution in that dictionary.

Therefore your memoized factorial function will only be slow on the first execution where it actually has to do the computations. The rest of the 999999 times it will simply look up the answers in the dictionary and avoid doing computations.

If you keep the dictionary inside the function, it will be destroyed after every time Python leaves the scope within the function (since all references to the dictionary will be destroyed when the function returns). Thus the dictionary will not be able to save its answers and will still remain slow for future executions.

[Check out the documentation for `timeit`.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#module-timeit)

Answer (score 3):

1. The memoization you wrote hangs on the answer permanently. This means that asking for the same answer multiple times is really fast. Only the first call ever needs to compute anything.
2. The way timeit benchmarks a function is to run it hundreds of times and taking an average of all the calls. This helps it be more accurate

This means 1 normal speed call and 99 super fast ones, are averaged together. That makes the memoized function look faster.

If you want to measure actual speed you need to clear your memoization dictionary after each test invocation.

Comment: Thanks, but did I get the actual speed already by moving the dict into the factorial function?

Comment: No, moving the dictionary to inside the function makes it useless, as it is local, and always empty.